# Using multiple yields to insert content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yield, content-for

I am trying to insert content on my page with `yield` but every time action removes whole content from the page. I have one main `yield` which is working fine:

```
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
    </div>
</body>
```

But inside that new content which is displayed on one page I have another `yield`:

```
<div class="container">
    <%= render 'admins/menu' %>
    <%= yield :admin %>
</div>
```

When user clicks on the menu which is rendered, new content should be displayed below that menu.

admins/_menu.html.erb

```
<div class="navbar">  
    <div class="navbar-inner">  
        <div class="container">  
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><%= link_to "Users", :controller => "admins", :action => "test" %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "1", ... %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "2", ... %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "3", ... %></li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

Controller:

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController

    def index
    end

    def test
        @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
end
```

test.html.erb

```
<% content_for :admin do %>

<h1>All users</h1>

...

<% end %>
```

When I click on the option 'Users' from menu, page refreshes, menu disappears and nothing is displayed inside `body'. I want the content to be displayed below menu. How to use that second yield and accomplish this functionality?

I hope the question is not confusing. If question is confusing, please write me in comments and I will edit it immediately.

Thank you :)

Comment: In which file is the `<%= yield :admin %>` code placed?

Comment: Just a hunch, but instead of `<%= yield :admin %>`, have you tried `<%= content_for :admin %>`?

Comment: @marzapower - In views/admins/index.html.erb

Comment: @CDub - I tried but it's the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, when you go to the `index` page you will get the piece of html that will be placed in the main layout, and this piece of html look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <%= render 'admins/menu' %>
    <%= yield :admin %>
</div>
```

This code will `yield :admin` properly.

When you go to the `test` page you do not have this html code anymore (since it only belongs to the `index` method). So, anything you put in the `content_for(:admin)` block will be ignored since no-one is printing it.

What you probably want to do is creating a shared layout for all your admin pages. Follow [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts) and you'll have your solution.

#### Solution

Edit the `application.html.erb` layout using this:

```
<%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>
```

instead of

```
<%= yield %>
```

Then create an `admins.html.erb` file inside the `layouts` folder to handle your admin pages' layout. Something like this:

```
<% content_for :content do %>
  <div class="container">
    <%= render 'admins/menu' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

Will do fine. Then in the `index.html.erb` and `test.html.erb` just place regular HTML content, without using the `content_for(:admin)` block. Everything should work fine and you'll have your custom admin template, with a slightly different look from regular pages.

Comment: Thank you but how can I now access that admins.html.erb file? I have a link <li><%= link_to "Admin dashboard", admin_dashboard_path %></li> on main page and in routes there was: match '/admin_dashboard',    to: 'admins#index',          via: 'get'.

Comment: The `admins.html.erb` file (placed in the `layouts` folder near the application main layout) will be automatically loaded for each method of the `AdminsController`. See that as an extension of the `application.html.erb` layout.

Comment: It works and it loads automatically but the problem is that admins.html.erb completely erases everything and now I have completely blank page only with the menu on top without any styles.

Comment: Have you modified the application layout as requested? You should just substitute the `<%= yield %>` line, not the whole file!

Comment: Yes. I substituted `<%= yield %>` with `<%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>`. Now when I click on 'Admin dashboard' on menu, only 'clean' `admins.html.erb` file opens without any styles.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the answer while typing, and pasted the wrong code. I updated the admin template. Let me know!

Comment: Thank you, it works now! I just recently started learning Rails so it was all a little bit confusing for me. You saved the day :)

Answer (score 1):

Calling `yield` doesn't work in helper modules, while `content_for` does, so you should replace your `yield` calls in the helper files.

Also noteworthy: using `provide` is recommended over `content_for` when you're only using the method in 1 place instead of multiple places.  You'll get better performance since it won't leave the buffer open while looking for more content, and your intent will be clearer to other developers that may see your code. (see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-provide)

Answer (score 0):

I found that you have to add an `yield` (without actually outputing) before the namespaced tags.

```html
<div>
  <% yield %>
  <div class="mt-3">
    <div class="text-2xl tracking-wide font-bold text-gray-900">
      heading
      <%= yield :heading %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="relative bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl mb-8 min-h-28">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
...
```