# yield :content doesn't show content_for :content

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, yield, content-for

I think I have the same issue with this.
[Using multiple yields to insert content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058412/using-multiple-yields-to-insert-content)

And I tried the solution. I tried to have `<%= yield :content %>` in my application.html.erb and have `content_for :content` and the `yield` inside, in my view. But it is not working on my app. Can you please explain more or give sample scenario on my problem?

The links inside, must not reload, so I will not use render partial on every template I will display.

I just recently started learning Rails so it was all a little bit confusing for me. Thank you.

[image]

I tried this; this is just an example I will fix the connection of sidebar later.

in my applicaion.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Clinks</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="container" >
        <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
        <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
        <section id="main-content">
            <section class="wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- %= yield % -->
                    <%=yield(:content) %>
                </div><!--/row -->
            </section><!--/wrapper -->
        </section><!--/main-content -->
    </section><!--/container -->
</body>
</html>
```

in my menu_tables.html.erb inside `layouts` folder.

```
<% content_for(:content) do %>
    <%= render 'menu_tables/sidemenu' %>
    <%= yield %>
<% end %>
<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

in my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'pages#home'
  resources :menu_tables, except: [:show]
end
```

then in _sidemenu.html.erb under menu_tables controller is the code for the links, so each links from sidebar have different sidemenu.

Answer (score 2):

May be you need to tell your controller to use `layout 'menu'`. In the link you provided names of the controller and layout matched, so it worked 'magically'.
See [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html):

> 2.2.14 Finding Layouts
>
> To find the current layout, Rails first looks for a file in
>   app/views/layouts with the same base name as the controller. For
>   example, rendering actions from the PhotosController class will use
>   app/views/layouts/photos.html.erb (or
>   app/views/layouts/photos.builder). If there is no such
>   controller-specific layout, Rails will use
>   app/views/layouts/application.html.erb or
>   app/views/layouts/application.builder. If there is no .erb layout,
>   Rails will use a .builder layout if one exists. Rails also provides
>   several ways to more precisely assign specific layouts to individual
>   controllers and actions.

(Note: you can check what layout is used in logs, look for line similar to `Rendered menu_items/index.html.erb within layouts/application`)

Comment: Thank you very much for this, it's make sense now. BIG HELP!!! But still not the answer I need. And I am thinking to go in `render partial` on each view.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't get what you actually want to make. Can you described it in other words? Is it different partial rendered in white links box for different page from sidebar?

Comment: Yes, you're right ^_^ each link from the sidebar have different links (*menu_links, inside links with the white background*) And if I clicked the link from menu_links, I don't want is to be reloaded. Is that possible? sorry for my english. I'm not good also at explaining ^_^ but the answer you gave is big help also.. thanks for that.